# How to display Upper and Lower range values on QCustomPlot Axis?

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

When the axis is dragged or zoomed no number will be displayed at the ends (top and bottom for Y-axis; left and right for X-axis).
Is it possible to display the upper and lower range **always** on the axis?

How to automatically make the end values of the axis get displayed on QCustomPlot?

I am using QCustomPlot 2.0.1

I expect a number always at the end of the axis.